# Added 'exit 0' to '.bashrc' and cannot login to server

Tags: bash, centos

I experimented with `$HOME/.bashrc` on my managed server CentOS 7 and decided to check how it behaves without the custom user settings.

I added `exit 0` before `source /etc/bashrc`.

From my brief look, it appeared that it deals only with prompts and colours. However, it seems it manages also users access control.

Now when I try to log in it kicks me out.

Why does this happen?

Is it possible to fix it remotely?

I'm usually login with SSH. Can I set some property or var to overcome the problem?

Comment: Your profiles are *sourced* in the login shell, not *executed*. So `exit` exits the login shell itself. All you can do is get root access (as a different user plus sudo).

Comment: You _might_ get access with `sftp user@host`, depending on how it's been configured on the host (internal or via a command). Failing that you'll need to get on to the system as a different user

Comment: I called the hosting company and they commented out the `exit 0` for me. Is it correct, that the `exit 0` on that place exits my login shell?

Comment: Yes. Temporarily replace it with `[ -t 1 ] && echo This is where I had exit` and see what happens. LEAVE THAT SHELL LOGGED ON AS ROOT. Then try logging in again with a different session.

Comment: @roaima I got: `Last login: Wed Sep 23 08:... from...' \n 'Where I got exit'

Comment: Exactly. So now you have your own answer. The `exit` would have exited your shell at that point

Comment: @roaima. This is thebest advice: ``LEAVE THAT SHELL LOGGED ON AS ROOT. Then try logging in again with a different session.``

Comment: When you're editing a system file, always that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash will also directly source `~/.bashrc` whenever it determines that it's being run by sshd, whether it's run interactively or not **(1)**.

The way bash determines that is by checking if **a)** the `SHLVL` envvar is less than 1 and **b)** the `SSH_CLIENT` or `SSH2_CLIENT` envvars are set or the stdin is a *connected socket*.

Example:

```
$ echo echo this sux > /tmp/.bashrc
$ HOME=/tmp bash -c true
$ HOME=/tmp SHLVL= SSH_CLIENT= bash -c true
this sux
```

The stdin could also be a socket when bash is called from ksh93, which is using unix domain socket pairs to implement pipes:

```
$ ksh93 -c ': | HOME=/tmp SHLVL= bash -c :'
this sux
```

I wasn't able to figure out any way to *bypass* the `~/.bashrc` at all when run via ssh (other than exploiting ssh misconfigurations, like the user being able to set extra environment variables).

In any case, AFAIK, a lot of sysadmins seem to rely on the user not being able to bypass it, whether warranted or not.

**(1)** this behaviour is [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files):

> Bash attempts to determine when it is being run with its standard input
> connected to a network connection, as when executed by the remote shell
> daemon, usually rshd, or the secure shell daemon sshd.  If bash  determines  it  is being run in this fashion, it reads and executes commands
> from `~/.bashrc`, if that file exists and is readable

On Debian, it will also source `/etc/bash.bashrc` before `~/.bashrc` (which is not documented).

Answer (score 3):

If bash behaves correctly, then `.bashrc` should only be called when the shell is an interactive shell. As a result, the following should work:

```
ssh server rm .bashrc
```

or

```
ssh server mv .bashrc .bashrc-off
```

since this creates a non-interactive shell on the server that is not affected by the problem in your .bashrc.

Unfortunately, many Linux distros deliver a `.profile` that calls `.bashrc` and in such a case, you are lost.

Comment: A correct behavior would be to run `isatty()` on `stdin`, but maybe it helps to use `ssh -n sever...`.

Comment: this answer is [wrong](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611107/414777)

Answer (score 0):

Summary from the comments.

Why `exit` in `.bashrc` leads to exit from SSH?

Comment by Paul_Pedant

> Your profiles are sourced in the login shell, *not executed*. So `exit` exits the login shell itself.

Is it possible to fix it remotely?

Comment by roaima

> You might get access with `sftp user@host`, depending on how it's been configured on the host (internal or via a command).

Best advice to avoid such cases by roaima

> LEAVE THAT SHELL LOGGED ON AS ROOT. Then try logging in again with a different session. When you're editing a system file, always that

...

I'm posting this comment in order to close the question. If @Paul_Pedant or @roaima post their answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

I just did the same thing. I added `exit 0` at the end of my server's `.zshrc`, which is Zsh's equivalent of Bash's `.bashrc`. Just like you, I couldn't login to my server, either.

I solved the problem by using `scp` command (secure copy) a `.zshrc` without `exit 0` to overwrite the existing one, such as:

`scp ~/.zsh/.zshrc my-server/.zsh/`

Voila! I'm able to login to my server again.