# Is there a ZDOTDIR equivalent to bash?

Tags: bash

Is there a way to move ~/.bashrc to somewhere else without leaving any trace (no symlink etc ) in ~/ ? Like Zsh does with the Environment variable ZDOTDIR ?

[This one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/98085/332496) only offers what I am not looking for.  The `--rcfile` is only good for initialising a new shell via the terminal prompt, it won't work for , say launching via a new terminal emulator (window in case of window manager ).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change the location of .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/98084/change-the-location-of-bashrc)

Comment: @ChrisDown Since the only answer to that question involves placing a symlink, I believe it will not fulfill the OPs requirements.

Comment: @AdminBee Oh, right, I missed that qualification. Thanks.

Comment: @Chris Down, I have seen that answer and it's not what I was looking for. I pasted the same link in my post.

Comment: You can use $BASH_ENV for non-interactive shells, but I don't know of anything that affects a login shell's evaluation of ~/.bashrc.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a `ZDOTDIR` equivalent to bash?

No, there's no direct equivalent for that.

> Is there a way to move `~/.bashrc` to somewhere else without leaving any trace (no symlink etc ) in `~/`

Yes, you can do that by changing the `HOME` environment variable:

```
$ echo echo LOL >/tmp/.bashrc
$ HOME=/tmp bash
LOL
$
```

For a *non-interactive* shell, you may use the `BASH_ENV` environment variable **(1)**:

```
$ BASH_ENV=/tmp/.bashrc bash -c true
LOL
```

Or do [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/611107).

> The `--rcfile` is only good for initialising a new shell via the terminal prompt, it won't work for, say launching via a new terminal emulator

That's not true. Most (all?) terminal emulators let you choose what command and arguments to run instead of the default shell.

---

**(1)** Despite the confusing claims from the bash manpage, `BASH_ENV` is different from the `ENV` which is sourced when bash is run in POSIX mode, because the former is used by *non-interactive* shells, but the latter by *interactive* shells. In any case, both are subject to command expansion, so they can be used to execute commands directly:

```
$ BASH_ENV='$(echo WTF >/dev/tty)' bash -c true
WTF
$ ENV='$(echo WTF >/dev/tty)' bash --posix -ic true
WTF
```

Comment: +1 for the detailed answer and also clarifying about the shell initialisation with terminal emulator /window manager part. In. The absence of resorting to any environment variable, modifying how the terminal emulator spawns a new shell would be the only option. But then again, I am worrying what happens when I change the login shell ? This may mess up if hard bind the settings in the terminal emulator.  Is there a workaround on , say pass --rcfile option if the shell is bash ' in any terminal emulator or window manager ?

Comment: About that ENV environment variable, that looked promising, but then again, it only works for posix mode so.. that kind of not what I was looking for.

Comment: Most terminal emulators have an option to start *login* shells (i.e. shells which source `~/.profile`, etc). E.g. `xterm -ls` (also settable via Xresources). That is (or were last time I have checked) the default in tmux.